# Check if Java code is running within a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven

I'm writing an Xtext-based code generator that may be called:

- directly (using `main(String[])` method)
- within Eclipse (as an Eclipse code generator plugin)
- through the 'xtext-maven-plugin'

Now I have to workaround some Maven-specific issues. In order to do this I need to know if my code is running within Maven or not.

My first idea was to check the `maven.home` system property like this:

```
if (System.getProperty("maven.home") != null) {
    // In Maven
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maven doesn't _run_ code, it compiles it. I'm not sure what specific problem you want to solve here. Are you running some code with the `exec-maven-plugin`?

Comment: No, I'm running code within a maven plugin!

Comment: Can't you modify the Maven plugin to set some custom system property instead?

Comment: maybe check for a pom.xml in the project root?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? What method did you end up using? Existence of pom.xml doesn't mean that the code is being run using Maven.

Comment: @Charles I used a "dirty" solution, setting a global variable from a Maven-plugin part and read it from the library-core part. Still looking for a nice solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you wrote a Maven plugin, and your code is part of that Maven plugin, and you are configuring that code by adding your to pom.xml under the build/plugins/plugin area, you are likely only using Maven to compile.

Checking an environmental variable will not tell you if you are "in the maven plugin" because the environmental variable exists even when maven isn't running.  To see if you are "in the maven plugin" you need to ask maven to do dependency injection and see if it fails (That's done through plexus containers, and if you don't recognize what I'm talking about, again you are not in the maven plugin).

I am 99% certain that your code fails when asking maven to compile it.  That's likely due to your compiler configuration have stricter requirements than the IDE you are using.  If so, the best answer is to fix your code to comply with the stricter Maven requirements; because, strict requirements are typically put in place to ensure the code runs properly in more scenarios.

I would also check your maven build configuration (pom.xml) to see if it is using the same version of java as your IDE.  Sometimes when you configuration your IDE, you select a different compilation level (say java 1.8) than your maven pom.xml would use (say Java 1.7).

Comment: I'm writing a code generator, that my be called directly (standalone) or through a third party maven-plugin (Xtext), that I can't change/extend easily. (Added this to the question)

Comment: Ok, Xtext is related to Tycho plugin.  Basically anything that touches the Tycho plugin is more an Eclipse environment build problem than a true Maven problem.  Basically Tycho is the abomination that makes Eclipse build within Maven, but actually doesn't allow Maven to do what _it does best_, which is manage the build configuration.  I'd wager that somewhere in the XText plugin, it effectively calls the command line equivalent tools of your build; but, considering it requires Tycho, you are likely hunting down Eclipse / Tycho bugs, not Maven ones.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm using Maven Surefire (which override the `System.out` console writer to  `org.apache.maven.surefire.api.report.ConsoleOutputCapture$ForwardingPrintStream`), I can detect I'm "in Maven":

```
if (System.out.getClass().getName().contains("maven")) {
    // in Maven
}
```

I use this mechanism to have extensive logging when my unit tests are ran interactively from the IDE, but I can reduce logging when the tests are ran "in Maven".